# Android: Implement a 1 second interval timer before calling a function

Tags: java, android, timer

I am trying to introduce a 1 second pause before I reset the game (resetGame()). After a button has been pressed. bAnswer1 text does equal ansewrArray[0]. The App force closes after the 1 second delay set in newQuestionTimer().

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

Timer timer = new Timer();

bAnswer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(bAnswer1.getText().toString().equals(answerArray[0]))
                {
                    bAnswer1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    newQuestionTimer();                 
                }
                else
                {
                    bAnswer1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    guess++;
                }
            }
        });

public void newQuestionTimer()
{
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            resetGame();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: that's what `postDelayed` is for. most likely you touch the views from `resetGame`, hence the crash

Comment: post the stacktrace and post resetgame code

Comment: public void resetGame()
    { 
            guess = 0;
            bAnswer1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
               bAnswer2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
               bAnswer3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
               bAnswer4.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        
    }

Comment: Apologies for the messy code in my reply.

Comment: @njzk2 How would I go about implementing postDelayed into newQuestionTimer(). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are updating ui from a timer which runs on a background thread. Ui can be updated only on the ui thread.

You can use a Handler

```
   Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bAnswer2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);           
            bAnswer3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);         
            bAnswer4.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: I did ponder using handler but opted for timer.schedule. I shall go and try this. Thanks

Comment: This did the trick thank you. Will set as accepted answer after the allotted waiting time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

          //your code here
          //you can add a block of code or a function cll

          //myFunction();

        }
    }, 1000);  //setting 1 second delay : 1000 = 1 second
```

I fount this sample from here 
http://wiki.workassis.com/android-execute-code-after-10-seconds