# How to add values by holding button in countdowntimer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I am making boxing countdown timer and to set how long round supposed to last I am using two button first "+" and second "-" my time add  every 5 seconds ex "5,10,15,20,25..." but I always I have to click to add 5 second. I would like to hold button and my value will add automatically what should I do?

I hope I add every important information in my question

my code from buttons and display

```
public void dodawanie1(View view) {
    iloscrund=iloscrund+1;
    display(iloscrund);

   public void odejmowanie1(View view) {
    if(iloscrund>1){
        iloscrund=iloscrund-1;
        display(iloscrund);
    }

}

  private void display(int numer) {
    TextView displayInteger=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    displayInteger.setText("" + numer);

}
```

odejmowanie means decrease value
dodawanie means increase value

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to determine between click and hold, use onTouchListener to determine hold button event.

[onTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Runnable and Handler class for do it.
this link should be useful.
[Android: Implement a 1 second interval timer before calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460499/android-implement-a-1-second-interval-timer-before-calling-a-function)

**activity_auto_inc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AutoIncActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:text="add"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/num" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AutoIncActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AutoIncActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

Button add;
TextView txt;
boolean isAddPressed = false;
Handler handler;
final int TIME_INTERVAL = 100;
final int STEP = 1;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_inc);

    handler = new Handler();
    add = findViewById(R.id.add);
    txt = findViewById(R.id.num);

    add.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    add.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.add) {
        isAddPressed = true;
        handler.postDelayed(new AutoInc(), TIME_INTERVAL);
    }
    return false;
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || 
       motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        isAddPressed = false;
    }
    return false;
}

private class AutoInc implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isAddPressed) {
            
txt.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString()) + 
STEP));
            handler.postDelayed(this, TIME_INTERVAL);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how?

Comment: use this link https://faradars.org/courses/fvand94062a-creating-custom-view-in-android-programming

Comment: see after 45 minutes for your answer

Comment: I will try for you.